# How to query tables to get cost of call

Tags: sql, cdr

What Query would I need to do to calculate cost of calls in mysql database?

Ive got two tables, one is a call log with call duration, and the other table is the tariff table with peak and offpeak rates, peaktime is 08:00:00 - 19:00:00 offpeak time is 19:00:00 - 08:00:00. rates for peak are say 10p a minute or 0.9992 a second or something on the lines of that. and offpeak 2p minute.

I want to know how to query the two tables to calculate the cost of call according to the call duration and the cost of the call - Rate per sec/minute.

Output would be on another table with CallerId, Source, Destination, call duration , cost of call

Comment: Can you give us more to work with? Table definitions, sample data, expected results, any queries you've already tried would all be helpful.

Comment: Let me just go get my psychic wizard hat. BRB.

Comment: I have edited the question. If any more details are needed then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems relatively straight forward (which usually means I am missing something).

Starting with assumptions. Say the CALL_LOG table looks like this:

```
CallerId
Source
Destination
Duration
CallStartTime
CallStopTime
```

. . . and the TARRIFF table looks like this:

```
Id
RateType (Peak or OffPeak)
RateStartTime
RateStopTime
Rate
```

And let's assume you are using Oracle, since I don't see that specifically mentioned. But you say CDRs, so probably lots of records, so maybe Oracle.  *(NOTE: I removed the Oracle specific code and decided to do this as an inner join. Might be too slow though, depending on volume.)*

And let's assume that the definition of an "off peak call" is a call that starts during an off-peak time, regardless of when it ends. (Note that this definition is critical to doing it correctly.)

Lastly, let's assume that there are only two rates, peak and off-peak, based on your comments. That seems strange, but ok. I would have thought that the times would differ by day, to allow for weekend rates, but you should be able to extrapolate.

So the cost for a call would then be

```
SELECT l.CallerId, 
       l.Source, 
       l.Destination, 
       l.Duration, 
       t.RateType, 
       l.Duration * t.Rate as Cost
FROM CALL_LOG l
  INNER JOIN TARRIF t
    ON l.CallStartTime BETWEEN t.RateStartTime and t.RateStopTime
```